# characterization of costant functions in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Are costant functions, say $f$, in $\mathbb{C}$ characterized by $f'(z)=0$  $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}$?

$f'(z)$ denotes the complex number such that $$ f(z+h)-f(z)=f'(z)h +o(\mid h \mid)$$ is valid.

Or equivalently $$f'(z) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$$

I asked this mainly because I don't think there is an equivalent result of Rolle Theorem (or Mean Value's) in $\mathbb{C}$ and $f'(z)=0$ is a local property. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f\colon\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ such that $f'(z)$ exists and equals zero  for all $z\in\mathbb C$ is constant. (If $f$ is defined on a non-connected domain, we only get that $f$ is locally constant, but that observation holds in the reals as well)

Assume $f(z_1)\ne f(z_2)$. Consider $g\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb C$, $t\mapsto f(z_1+t(z_2-z_1))$. Then you have $g(t+h)=g(t)+o(|h|)$ and are reduced to the real case.